# SAP UI5 Fiori Planning Calendar Switch days by scroll

Tags: scrollbar, sapui5

Currently, in SAP UI5 Fiori Planning Calendar there is no option to scroll the days. It only allows switching days by Clicking or tapping the arrows to navigate to the next or previous interval.

[image]

Is there any way to add a scrollbar to switch between days. 
I've searched but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. 
The Planning Calendar header is fixed and does not allow such customizations. 
Also, the content grid below does not support such scrolling.

You might want to use different views, e.g. change the default view to “1 Month”, in order to move quickly forward.
As time is unlimited, you would also need an “indefinite” scrollbar.

Comment: the thing is if I need to drag and drop an appointment to a date which is 2-3 months from current date it's not possible

Comment: If you need to drag and drop an appointment to a date, which is several months in the future, you might first switch to a proper view, 
in this particular case ‘Months’ view and drag the appointment 2 or 3 months from the current date. 
This will allow you, to change just the month. The day and time is not expected to change.

Comment: If you want to move the appointment from a specific date & time to another specific date and time, which is 2-3 months from current date, then drag & drop is not the recommended approach. In this case, the recommendation is a popup or dialog with the appointment settings to be shown on appointment press, where the user can do more fine-grained adjustments to the appointment.

Comment: Please see the following two samples; you also can download the coding: [PlanningCalendarDnD](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendarDnD/preview), [PlanningCalendarModifyAppointments](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendarModifyAppointments/preview)

Comment: yes,I'll check but the user's requirement is the one I mentioned